# yolov5 : Can i add more epochs on the model already done custom training?

Tags: python, yolov5

I'm trying to make image detection model with 30,000 images.
I just tried 5 epochs which took about 5 hours of training.

The question is, if I want to simply add more epochs on the same model, how can i do that?
Is there a way that I can load custom trained model?

Since it takes so long, I wish I can continue training from 5 epochs already done training.
I'm using colab, and I experienced a few times loosing connection during the training so I'm afraid of giving more epochs from the start of training.

Comment: I found I can use "--weights" argument with "last.pt". is it right?

Comment: Yes,  --weights last.pt will be perfect solution

Comment: If you are using `YOLOv5`, you should go with `--resume` [More Info](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/1560)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the standard yolo training command and provide the path to your previously training model in the -- weights paramater.

```
!python train.py --img 960 --batch 20 --epochs 10 --data dataset.yaml --weights your_model.pt --cache --exist-ok
```

Comment: is this command also keep epoch learning rate? Or is it gonna start over like it is the first epoch

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't make any changes to the number of epochs once you have started the training.
Simply put if you have trained a model for 5 epochs you can't run it for another 5 and make it 10.